# Add a number to a file name if does not exist or increase the number if it exist

Tags: java, strings, regex

I'm currently working on a solution to add a number to a file name if the number does not exist or increase de number by one if the number exist.

For instance if you input "filename.jpeg" the code will add a 1 and return "filename(1).jpeg".

In case the number already exist in the name for instance "hello_world(3).pdf" it will increase it by one and return "hello_world(4).pdf".

This logic is used to add files to a Recycle Bin where files will be sent from different parts of the system and they need to have unique names.

The code must

- Find a number between parenthesis next to the file extension
- If this number does NOT exist add it
- If it does exist increase it by one

(another method will run this iteratively until the name is is not found in the Recycle Bin)

Any suggestions or improvements ?

Should you require any information please do not hesitate to ask away !

```
public String getFileNameNumbered(String fileName){

    int indexLastDot = fileName.lastIndexOf('.');
    String extension = fileName.substring(indexLastDot);
    String regex = "[(]\\d+[)]" + extension + "$";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(fileName);

    if(matcher.find()){ //Check if the file name contains a number eg. (1).jpeg
        String numberExtension = matcher.group();
        pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
        matcher = pattern.matcher(numberExtension);
        if(matcher.find()){ // check only for the number and extract it
            int number = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group());
            number++;
            fileName = fileName.replaceAll(regex, "(" + number + ")" + extension);
        }

    } else { //add a number to the file
        fileName = fileName.substring(0, indexLastDot) + "(" + 1 + ")" + extension;
    }
    return fileName;
}
```

Comment: What if the filename after you add the number still clashes with an existing file?

Answer (score 3):

## Bugs

What happens when you encounter a file like `README` with no extension?

Although unlikely, your `extension` could contain characters that have special meaning in a regex pattern, so must be quoted:

```
    String regex = "[(]\\d+[)]" + Pattern.quote(extension) + "$";
```

## Regex

You are not using all of the power of the regex engine.  Moreover, you are creating possibly dozens of regex `Pattern` objects where a single regex would do.  Additionally, you are using `\d+` to find the digits in a string where the first character is known to be a `(` and the string ends with `)` followed by `extension` (a string of known length) so could easily be extracted using just a substring operation.

You want to find something like:

```
a.filename(99).ext
```

So let's design a regex which will do everything.  It will extract the base name, an optional number in parenthesis, and the extension:

```
(.*?)(?:\((\d+)\))?(\.[^.]*)$
(   )                         - a capturing group of
 .*?                          -   any characters (non-greedy), followed by
     (?:         )            - a non-capturing group of
        \(     \)             -   literal parentheses
          (   )               -   surrounding a capturing group of
           \d+                -     digits
                  ?           -   (zero or one occurrences)
                   (       )  - a capturing group of
                    \.        -   a literal period
                      [^.]*   -   followed by any number of non-periods
                            $ - at the end of the string
```

The **non-greedy** initial match is required to prevent `(99)` from becoming part of the initial filename and the following optional section matching with zero occurrences.

(Of course, you'll have to double all `\` characters to create a Java string literal.)

If this regular expression matches:

- `.group(1)` will contain the start of the filename,
- `.group(2)` will contain 1 or more digits, or will be `null`,
- `.group(3)` will contain the extension.

If the regex does not match, then there is no period in the filename, like `README`, and you'll have to decide how you want to handle that.

Answer (score 2):

> The code must
>
> - Find a number between parenthesis next to the file extension
> - If this number does NOT exist add it
> - If it does exist increase it by one

So you're operating on a filename string, assuming that incrementing-or-defaulting will be enough for use on the filesystem. This assumption may not hold water.

I suggest that you:

- do find an index in the provided string, but only to remove it and extract the stem before it and extension after
- do a directory search for files with the same stem and extension, finding the maximum existing index
- increment that index
- form a new filename based on what you know to be the pattern-matched stem, incremented index and pattern-matched extension

### Suggested

Very roughly, and without much mind for optimisation:

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {
    private static final String barePatternStr =
        "^"          // Start
        + "(?<stem>" // Capture: the filename stem
        +     "[^.]*"  // Any non-dot stem chars
        + ")"        // End of capture
        + "(?:"      // Non-capturing group for index
        +     "\\("  // Literal paren
        +     "\\d+" // At least one digit, greedy
        +     "\\)"  // Literal paren
        + ")?"       // Index is optional
        + "(?<ext>"  // Capture: any extension
        +     "\\."  // Literal dot
        +     ".*?"  // Anything else, lazy
        + ")?"       // Extension is optional
        + "$";       // End

    private static final Pattern barePattern = Pattern.compile(barePatternStr);

    private static final String filesysPatternStr =
        "^"           // Start
        + "%s"        // Stem field (needs to be escaped)
        + "\\("       // Literal paren
        + "(?<index>" // Capture: the numeric index
        +     "\\d+"  // At least one digit, greedy
        + ")"         // End of capture
        + "\\)"       // Literal paren
        + "%s"        // Extension field (needs to be escaped)
        + "$";        // End

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println(findNext(
            Path.of("."),
            "test.txt"
        ));
    }

    private static String findNext(Path parent, String fileName) throws IOException {
        Matcher bareMatcher = barePattern.matcher(fileName);

        // Ignore any index to form the bare filename
        bareMatcher.matches();
        String stem = bareMatcher.group("stem"),
               ext = bareMatcher.group("ext");
        if (ext == null) ext = "";

        String globStr = filesysPatternStr.formatted(
            Pattern.quote(stem), Pattern.quote(ext)
        );
        int index = getHighestIndex(parent, Pattern.compile(globStr));

        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        bareMatcher.appendReplacement(
            result,
            "${stem}(%d)${ext}".formatted(index + 1)
        );
        return result.toString();
    }

    private static int getHighestIndex(Path parent, Pattern glob) throws IOException {
        try (Stream<Path> files = Files.list(parent)) {
            return files
                .map(path -> {
                    Matcher globMatcher = glob.matcher(path.getFileName().toString());
                    if (globMatcher.matches())
                        return Integer.parseInt(globMatcher.group("index"));
                    return null;
                })
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .mapToInt(i -> i)
                .max()
                .orElse(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Performance may vary by doing a first-pass filter on the file system with a simple glob `*` where the index would be, if the OS and JVM have efficient globbing; but this is illustrative of the algorithm.

Comment: @AJNeufeld Right; that's a consequence of an earlier iteration that had an extension that was too greedy. Should be better now.